# How do I install Mir?

Tags: software-installation, mir

How do I install Mir on Ubuntu 12.10?
Can I use it side by side with X?

> <sub>Though this question is for Ubuntu 12.10.You are still encouraged to give generic answers for all supported versions and distro's if they are few and same.</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are Running saucy(13.10)

```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install mir-demos unity-system-compositor
```

**Source**:

- [Mir: Installing pre-built packages on a PC](http://unity.ubuntu.com/mir/installing_prebuilt_on_pc.html)

## PPA

[**Warning**](https://launchpad.net/~mir-team/+archive/system-compositor-testing)

> Please use with care - this PPA contains new and experimental releases
>   of the Ubuntu 13.10 and 14.04 graphics stack. It currently contains a
>   key feature, multimonitor meant for testing. Please see
>   https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Mir/MultiMonitorTesting for more information
>   on testing.
>
> Known major issues:
>   - Input from another VT will be entered into a running XMir session - BE CAREFUL NOT TO SWITCH TO A VT AND ENTER YOUR PASSWORD WHILE HAVING
>   AN APPLICATION CONNECTED TO THE INTERNET OPEN.
>
> ```
> https://bugs.launchpad.net/xmir/+bug/1192843
> https://bugs.launchpad.net/mir/+bug/1102757
> ```
>
> - this PPA will not work on Radeon or Nouveau drivers
>     https://bugs.launchpad.net/xmir/+bug/1217005
>     https://bugs.launchpad.net/xmir/+bug/1217009
> - all multimonitor bugs can be found here
>     https://bugs.launchpad.net/xmir/+bugs?field.tag=multimonitor
> - no proprietary driver support (dependent on 3rd parties)
> - no bypass composition support at the system compositor level
>     https://bugs.launchpad.net/mir/+bug/1109963
> - no power management enabled
>     https://bugs.launchpad.net/xmir/+bug/1193222
> - no VESA support
>     https://bugs.launchpad.net/mir/+bug/1118903

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mir-team/system-compositor-testing
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

After that, restart Ubuntu, or:

```
sudo restart lightdm
```

https://launchpad.net/~mir-team/+archive/system-compositor-testing

## Compiling

Downloading the [mir code from launchpad](https://launchpad.net/mir), and installing its dependencies

**Downloading**

```
bzr branch lp:mir
```

**Dependencies**

```
sudo apt-get install devscripts equivs cmake gcovr lcov pdebuild astyle

sudo apt-get build-dep mir
```

**Compiling**

```
 mkdir build
 cd build
 cmake ..
```

Current output of `cmake ..`

> -- doxygen 1.8.4 (>= 1.8.0) available - enabling make target doc
>
> -- pdebuild NOT found, pre-push is going to FAIL
>
> -- Env. variable MIR_ANDROID_NDK_DIR not set, pre-push is going to FAIL
>
> -- Env. variable MIR_ANDROID_SDK_DIR not set, pre-push is going to FAIL
>
> You have called ADD_LIBRARY for library 3rd_party without any source
>   files. This typically indicates a problem with your CMakeLists.txt
>   file
>
> -- Defining targets: check_discover_tests_in_mir_acceptance_tests and discover_tests_in_mir_acceptance_tests
>
> -- Defining targets: check_discover_tests_in_mir_integration_tests and discover_tests_in_mir_integration_tests
>
> -- Defining targets: check_discover_tests_in_mir_unit_tests and discover_tests_in_mir_unit_tests CMake Warning at
>   tools/vera++/CMakeLists.txt:16 (message):   vera++ not available -
>   disabling make target style_check

**Building and testing**

```
 make -j8
 ctest
```

**Installing mir**

```
make install
```

> For GL accelerated clients to use Mir they need to use a patched version of Mesa that supports Mir. The patch is hosted on GitHub:

```
git clone https://github.com/RAOF/mesa.git
```

Compile as per normal instructions and pass –with-egl-platforms="mir,drm" to the configure options. You will need libmirclient installed as shown above.
    Building X.Org

> To run an X server inside Mir you need to build a patched version of
>   the X.Org X server. The patch is hosted on GitHub:

```
git clone https://github.com/RAOF/xserver.git
```

> To run an X server inside Mir you also need a patched version of your
>   X.Org video driver.
>
> The three drivers - Intel, Radeon, and Nouveau - are available on
>   Launchpad:

```
 bzr branch lp:~mir-team/mir/xf86-video-intel-vladmir
 bzr branch lp:~mir-team/mir/xf86-video-ati-vladmir
 bzr branch lp:~mir-team/mir/xf86-video-nouveau
```

Compile as per normal instructions. These need to be built after the X server, as they depend on new interfaces there.
Building Unity System Compositor

If you want to run a full system using XMir then you need to use a system compositor. For Ubuntu we have a system compositor [project on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/unity-system-compositor). Compile with the following:

```
 bzr branch lp:unity-system-compositor
 cd unity-system-compositor
 mkdir build
 cd build
 cmake ..
```

Source:

- [Mir: Building the source for a PC](http://unity.ubuntu.com/mir/building_source_for_pc.html)

<sup>Disclaimer: I just read the documentation, I did not test this out!</sup>

Comment: Will it work for Ubuntu 13.04? I know it's EOL but I have an ISO and I could try it in VM.I don't want to break my working installation

Comment: @adityapatil, 13.04 IS EOL, so no idea. Try it in a VM, and if it works, it works, if not, then try it on a supported Ubuntu version.

Comment: Just think you are a surgeon and just before the operation, you tell the patient "This machine is new,I've just read the documentation,I did not test it out". He will die!!!

Comment: @adityapatil, thats why you are testing it out in a virtual environment. There is no need for anybody to die. And Will test this out when i am at home. So, be patient, or test it out in a VM

Comment: I'll try it out and let you know.

Comment: @adityapatil, thanks. Been meaning to try mir out, after i read this: [Some of Linu's Most Popular Games Will Run Natively On Mir | OMG! Ubuntu!](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/02/mir-sdl-support)